# How does Windows know if a program is not responding? Clarify for multithreaded program

Tags: windows

As a follow-up question to this conversation:
[How does Windows know if a program is not responding?](https://superuser.com/questions/961843/how-does-windows-know-if-a-program-is-not-responding)

"How does Windows know if a program is not responding?
An application is considered to be not responding if it is not waiting for input, is not in startup processing, and has not called PeekMessage within the internal timeout period of 5 seconds."
I've inverited an application that has many threads that call PeekMessage.
If Windows is watching for each thread to use it's PeekMessage loop in less than 5 seconds or there is a main thread/loop that's being monitored that PeekMessage is called within 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Each thread that has allocated a message queue, must handle messages within the timeout allocated by Windows. This behavior includes the main thread.

Maybe [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues) would help you understand.